# MUI Drawer with fixed positioning and top of 0

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, frontend

Basically I have a scrollable drawer component on the left side and content with cards on the right side. I'm using [MUI permanent drawer][1] which acts as a filter panel. The user can select bunch of filters there and this will change the content on the right side. I ended up using Drawer for the left filter panel because I wanted the filter options to be in it's own separate panel so that they don't overflow the actual content on the right side even if there are lots of options.

Now I want to create a navigation at the top of the page with a few tabs. When user clicks on tabs, they will be redirect to the same filter and content but with different data. That is not a problem. My problem is that since the drawer has a fixed position with top of 0, the nav bar is not visible. I can't change the positioning of filter to relative or absolute because it would mess up how scrolling worked when the position wasn't changed. Is there a way to achieve this?

```html
import { AppBar, Box, Drawer,  Toolbar, } from "@mui/material"


export default function App() {
  return (
    <Box>
      <AppBar position="static">
        <Toolbar>
          Tab1
          Tab 2
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <Drawer
        anchor="left"
        variant="permanent"
        open
        disablePortal
      >
        <p>Filter 1</p>
        <p>Filter 2</p>
        <p>Filter 1</p>
        <p>Filter 2</p>
        <p>Filter 1</p>
        <p>Filter 2</p>
        <p>Filter 1</p>
        <p>Filter 2</p>
        <p>Filter 1</p>
        <p>Filter 2</p>
        <p>Filter 1</p>
        <p>Filter 2</p>
        <p>Filter 1</p>
        <p>Filter 2</p>
        <p>Filter 1</p>
        <p>Filter 2</p>
        <p>Filter 1</p>
        <p>Filter 2</p>
      </Drawer>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't set the top to 0, rather to the height of AppBar.
So if the AppBar is say 50px, then Drawer top should be 50px.

Comment: It kinda works, but not fully, if set the value for top to anything other than 0, the scrolling gets weird and I can't scroll all the way thru the content inside the drawer. It stops at the viewport. Not sure what is going on.